# How to design an interceptor in PHP CodeIgniter like in Java structs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, interceptor

When I am using CodeIgniter to implement a small application, I want all business checking functions in controllers could be defined outside the controller for more flexible.

The checking functions just like session checking, user information completion checking, or has user post an article, and so on.

Firstly, I tried to use helper to implement. In my core controller which extended from `CI_Controller` I wrote a `check` function:

```
protected function check () {
    $this->checked = TRUE;
    $methods = func_get_args();
    foreach ($methods as $method) {
        $m = 'check_' . $method;
        if (!function_exists($m)) {
            $this->load->helper("filters/$m");
        }

        if ($m() === FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Then in any controller I can use this method to check my business logic like this:

```
public function something ()
    if (!$this->check('session')) {
        return $this->relogin();
    }
    // ...
    if (!$this->check('userinfo')) {
        return $this->redirect('settings');
    }
    // ...
    if (!this->check('has_post')) {
        // ...  
    }
    // ...
}
```

But it has a problem that all helper function are global, and can't invoke protected functions in `$CI` instance. I didn't find a way how to invoke a instance function outside like JavaScript's `call`/`apply`.

So I turned to check the hook document of CI. But I don't think it helps, because the hook point can't be inside of any controller functions. It must be outside.

At last, I can just fallback to put all checking functions into core controller class. So I wonder is there any way to use interceptor as in Java structs?

Comment: im not 100% sure what Java structs are, however you can do what you are attempting by using libraries. These are available to use in your controller like helpers, but they are a class structure (using public/private/protected).

Comment: Thx @mic. But by using libraries also cause my problem in helpers, which can't call controller protected methods outside controller.

Comment: Ah ok I see what your problem is, you're trying to call protected methods methods from external classes. If this is only to prevent the user being able to access them via the URL, you do some routing to prevent certain methods being called. $route['class/method/(:any)'] = 'class/index'; or show a 404. To do this you need to make the methods public but it should work.

Comment: Yes. This should work but a little dirty. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I agree it's a little dirty. The problem with protected methods is they can only be called from within the parent class or one of it children. It might be worth refactoring the controller to be very lightweight and either use a helper or library to load the classes enabling you to use call the methods. That way you can build an OOP API that can be used all over your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use _remap()!

add a function into the class:

```
_remap($method, $params=[]) {
  if (true) {
    $this->$method($params);
  } else {
    $this->method5();
  }
}
```

The logic is that everytime someone call a Method, the API would FIRST execut the REMAP function... inside you can do whatever you need and then decide if the API should execute the called method or another or none...